# Insert and restore BLOB values SubType = Text Field Firebird Java

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird

I'm building a project, and I came across a problem
with a Blob field I created in the database Firebird.
This field would be referring to a field observations, which
I do not want to limit the amount of text which the user will enter.

But I have a problem and do not know how I save and read this field.

I'm using JDBC to use the insert prepareStatement stmt
stmt.set ... - For the blob do not know how to do and also
do not know how to convert the String value for the field

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PreparedStatement.setString()` and `ResultSet.getString()` and the Firebird driver will convert it to/from a blob for you if you are using a `BLOB SUB_TYPE 1` (aka `BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT`). You do need to ensure that your connection characterset is the same as the blob character set, otherwise you could get incorrect characterset conversions.

Other options are to explicitly create a Clob (using `Connection.createClob()`) and set that on the statement, or to use the `setCharacterStream` method.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to blob, I found [this example](http://studyjava.org/client-side-scripts/convert-string-to-blob-and-blob-to-string):

```
//Convert String to Blob
String data = “hello world”;
java.sql.Blob blob = org.hibernate.Hibernate.createBlob(data.getBytes());

//Convert Blob to String
byte[] bdata = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());
String data1 = new String(bdata);
```

Take a look at [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementSetBlob.htm) `setBlob` for a prepared statement. Here's a piece. From their example it looks like you can call `setBlob` on a `PreparedStatement`

```
java.sql.Blob blob = null;
try {
  conn = getConnection();
  // prepare blob object from an existing binary column
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select photo from my_pictures where id = ?");
  pstmt.setString(1, "0001");
  rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
  rs.next();
  blob = rs.getBlob(1);

  // prepare SQL query for inserting a new row using setBlob()
  String query = "insert into blob_table(id, blob_column) values(?, ?)";
  // begin transaction
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);

  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  pstmt.setString(1, "0002");
  pstmt.setBlob(2, blob);

  int rowCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();
  System.out.println("rowCount=" + rowCount);
  // end transaction
  conn.commit();
```